# Как работает синхронный вызов в микросервисах?

Tags: микросервисы

Читаю книгу Сэма Ньюмена "Создание микросервисов", там есть такая фраза:

> With a synchronous blocking call, a microservice sends a call of some kind to a
> downstream process (likely another microservice) and blocks until the call has com‐
> pleted, and potentially until a response has been received.

В русском переводе:

> При синхронном блокирующем вызове микросервис отправляет какой-либо вы-
> зов нижестоящему процессу (вероятно, другому микросервису) и блокируется
> до завершения вызова и, возможно, до получения ответа.

Я хочу уточнить - блокируется микросервис (мс) вообще целиком или все-таки только поток, из которого сделан вызов?

Я себе представляю работу так: пусть у нас 2 мс, А и В, сделаны на Spring Web или любом другом веб-фреймворке. Каждого мс по одному экземпляру.

- Пользователь что-то щелкает.
- запрос уходит в А.
- в А создается новый поток (или берется из пула - не важно) для обслуживания пришедшего запроса.
- А вызывает В и ждет от него ответа.
- при этом блокируется не весь А, а только поток, который обслуживает запрос.

Стало быть, если другой пользователь тоже что-то щелкнет, то его запрос тоже будет обслуживаться отдельным потоком, и поэтому сам мс А не блокируется, продолжает нормально работать. Так почему тогда в книге написано, что блокируется микросервис?

Comment: Это зависит от реализации, что конкретно блокируется. Можно реализовать неблокирующие вызовы, можно блокировать сервис специально даже при неблокирующем вызове, например для обеспечения идемпотентности (это дичь так делать, но бывает).

Comment: Может где-то ранее в книге сказано, что автор в ней рассматривает  микросервис как один поток?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если дальше текст почитать, то там объясняется, что имеется в виду. Если я правильно понял, то речь там не о **потоках ОС или программы**, а о **потоке управления**.

Ниже там, например, объясняется, что "Async/Await and When Asynchronous Is Still Blocking", то есть программная асинхронность может и не блокирует **поток ОС/программы**, но блокирует **поток управления**. Таким образом, под **неблокирующим вызовом** там понимается такой вызов, который передаёт какие-то данные в другой модуль/сервис и **не ожидает (синхронно либо асинхронно) ничего в ответ**. Ответ придёт уже не в этот поток управления, а в какой-то другой обработчик этого микросервиса, который уже этот ответ каким-то образом обработает и на него отреагирует.

То есть противопоставляются две парадигмы работы **потока управления** (flow control):

1. **Блокирующий** запрос:

```
Послали запрос -> Ожидание ответа (включая асинхронное) -> Реакция на ответ
```

2. **Неблокирующий** запрос:

```
Послали запрос -> Забыли про запрос, работаем дальше
Пришёл ответ -> Реакция на ответ
```

Второй вариант можно организовать, например, с помощью **брокера сообщений** (`RabbitMQ`, `Kafka` и т.п.)

В общем, в данном случае вам нужно обратить внимание не на то, что вызов **синхронный**, а на то, что он **блокирующий**. Если вы сделаете этот вызов **асинхронным** или **конкурентным** (запустите его в отдельном потоке), это всё-равно не сделает этот вызов **неблокирующим** *с точки зрения микросервисной архитектуры*, вот в чём тут суть.

Comment: Т.е. сам микросервис может "физически" не блокироваться и продолжать работать за счет того что новые запросы обрабатываются в разных потоках. Но блокируется он как бы "логически", потому что каждый поток не продолжает работу, пока не получит ответ. Верно я понял? И именно про такую "логическую" блокировку пишет автор.

Comment: @johnymkp Если я правильно понял автора, то да, именно так. Причём, даже ведь нельзя говорить, что блокируется поток. Если вы понимаете в асинхронности, то при асинхронном ожидании поток не блокируется, он может быть отдан для работы другого кода. Но потом рано или поздно управление должно будет вернуться туда, где был асинхронный вызов. Оно может даже другим уже потоком вернуться при определённых условиях. Поэтому речь тут именно о логической блокировке, если можно так сказать, да.